# How make a nginx cache like a varnish?

Tags: caching, nginx, heroku, proxy

I'm hosting a website in heroku and using nginx in a cloud host as a proxy.

In my cloud host I defined this:

```
## /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
charset utf-8;
listen 80;

server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

location /api {
    proxy_pass http://mywebsite-api.herokuapp.com;
}

location /auth {
    proxy_pass http://mywebsite-api.herokuapp.com;
}

location / {
    fastcgi_cache CACHE_KEY;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;

    proxy_pass http://mywebsite-fe.herokuapp.com;
}
}

## in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
.......
http {

  fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=CACHE_KEY:100m inactive=60m;
  fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
  .....
```

I want to make a static content in nginx, like a varnish. How can I do this using nginx with a proxy to heroku?

Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Change fastcgi_ to proxy_. The fastcgi_ versions are for php-fpm.